# Change cart item prices for specific product categories in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, custom-taxonomy, price

I would like to change regular price to custom price of products in the cart for specific categories only ('t-shirts-d','socks-d','joggers-d','boxers-d') as each of the products share 2 different categories.

I tried doing so and it worked but the custom price affects on other categories too, and I want to only show the original price for other categories('t-shirts','socks','joggers','boxers').

I Need help on this.

Here is my code so far:

```
function changeprice($html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key){
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        //$thepro = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$product = $cart_item['data'];
 $heading_nicename = array('t-shirts-d','socks-d','joggers-d','boxers-d');
 //$heading_nicename1 = array('t-shirts','socks','joggers','boxers');
   $termsother =  $heading_nicename;
 foreach( $termsother as $termsnew ) {
  if (is_cart()) {
            $price_adjusted = 666.666666667; // your adjustments here
            $price_base = $cart_item['data']->sale_price;
            if (!empty($price_adjusted)) {
                if (intval($price_adjusted) > 0) {
                    $cart_item['data']->set_price($price_adjusted);
                } /*else {
                    $html = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price($price_base) 
  . '</span>';
                }*/
            }
        }
     }
   }
   }
    add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'changeprice', 100, 3);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**THE RIGHT WORKING HOOK *(Updated)*:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_cart_items_prices', 10, 1 );
function change_cart_items_prices( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( has_term( array('t-shirts-d','socks-d','joggers-d','boxers-d'), 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ){
            $price_adjusted = 666.666666667; // your adjustments here
            if ( ! empty( $price_adjusted ) && intval( $price_adjusted ) > 0) {
                $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price_adjusted );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

> This time everything work on cart and on checkout pages. **Totals are updated too**.

Comment: Thankyou so much, but the code works only for one product out of 6 products. It shows custom price on the second product in the cart but not for the rest.

Comment: It seems the price changes only on the simple products but not on the variable product. I tried the if is_type = variable but not working

Comment: @SandeepTete So this updated version worked this time for you…